# Push notifications with Ionic.io

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic development and i am trying to use notifications with Ionic app.

I have followed the tutorial to send notifications using Ionic.io account.

```
 var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
      push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
    });
```

I am able to get the token in the console.

**I need to known :**

> 1. Is this token also visible on the ionic.io dashboard as in the users column i am not able to see any user.
> 2. what if i have to send notifications from my own server so i need to save these tokens on my server with some username and accordingly can select the users and send the notification. how do i send this token to my server for saving and how to send notification to this user using some php code on my server.

thanks

Comment: 1. No, you can't see any token in Ionic Dashboard. 2. You have to save the token in your database by Post (data:token.token). Refer this link to send push notification http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push.

Comment: i am new to ionic can you suggest code through which i can send a post request to my server to save this token .normally we use $http service. can we use this in the app.js file.

Comment: Something like this.$http({ headers : {
   'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  },
  url:module_url+"/customer/addDeviceId",
  method:"POST",
  data:{token:token.token,mobile_no:response.mobile_no}
}).success(function(data){
          
         });